# Sliding navigational menu (sliiide.js) works partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide a navigational menu. I am using [sliiide.min.js](https://github.com/ahmedrad/sliiide). The following settings work when I stay at the top of the page, but as I scrolls down and click to slide the menu it gives a blank white portion in the place of the actual menu, which I can't figure out how to sort out. If any of you experienced similar problems before, please kindly share. I am giving full code.

THE HTML MENU

```
<div id="tablet-mobile-menu" class="sidr left" style="visibility: hidden; display: block; left: 0px;">
    <div class="utility-nav">
        <div class="main-menu">
            <ul id="burger-menu" class="links clearfix">
                <li class="menu-15461 first">
                    <a href="" id="hamburger-subscribe" class="burger" style="color: #fc0; text-transform: uppercase;">Follow Us On</a>
                </li>
                <div class="utility-menu">
                    <ul id="hamburger-utility-menu" class="links clearfix">
                        <li class="menu-7731 first">
                            <a href="" id="facebook" class="facebook burger">Facebook</a>
                        </li>
                            <a href="" id="pinterest" class="pinterest burger">Pinterest</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <li class="menu-15461 first" style="">
                    <a href="" id="hamburger-subscribe" class="burger" style="color: #fc0; text-transform: uppercase;">Sections</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <p>Men's Health, The Brand Men Live By</p>
            <p>Copyright © 2016 Rodale Inc. No reproduction, transmission or display is permitted without the written permissions of Rodale Inc.</p>
            <p>
                <a href="">Privacy Policy.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <a href="">About Us.</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HERE IS THE JS CONFIGURATION:

```
<?php $this->script()->captureStart(); ?>

                                    var settings = {
                                    toggle: "#menu-btn-toggle", // the selector for the menu toggle, whatever clickable element you want to activate or deactivate the menu. A click listener will be added to this element.
                                    exit_selector: ".is-active", // the selector for an exit button in the div if needed, when the exit element is clicked the menu will deactivate, suitable for an exit element inside the nav menu or the side bar
                                    animation_duration: "0.1s", //how long it takes to slide the menu
                                    place: "left", //where is the menu sliding from, possible options are (left | right | top | bottom)
                                    animation_curve: "cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.01, 0.57, 1.03)", //animation curve for the sliding animation
                                    body_slide: true, //set it to true if you want to use the effect where the entire page slides and not just the div
                                    no_scroll: true, //set to true if you want the scrolling disabled while the menu is active
                                    };

                                    $('#tablet-mobile-menu').sliiide(settings); //initialize sliiide



<?php $this->script()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

HERE IS THE HTML WHERE THE CLICK OR TOGGLE BUTTON RESIDES:

```
<div id="menu-btn">
    <a href="/" title="Menu" id="menu-btn-toggle" class="clickable">
       <!--<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
       <!--<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
        <span></span>  
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the slider is there its just that its sitting at the top of the page so what your seeing is the bottom of the menu.

have you tried to add a CSS style to the top of the navigation so its sticks to the top of page even when scrolling.

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you add a JS fiddle for this

Comment: I wish I could its quite big html and css I have to make a much smaller version of it for jsfiddle ... to give you some more info when I use a # instead of "/" in <a href="/" title="Menu" id="menu-btn-toggle" class="clickable"> it works because I scrolls back to the top but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: it sounds more like a CSS issue really. It sounds like the height of the menu is the same as the page your using it on.

Comment: yes, it could be and thought the same before, can you suggest something how to solve that if that were the actual case?